# jQuery: how to set selected in jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, dialog

My question is how can I preset a selected option to the clicked item's respective department?

UPDATE:

I tried @Ryan Wilson's solution, and I can see the old "selected" attribute is remove and new one is added to HTML,
But not sure why the interface still showing the old "selected"
[image]

This is my js. I'm using [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
$(function () {
  let dialog, form;

  function updateInfo() {
    //update item name
    let newItemName = $('#item-name').val();
    $(clickedItemName)[0].innerText = newItemName;

    //update item's department name
    let newDepartmentName = $('#select-department').find(":selected").text();
    $(currentDepartment)[0].innerText = newDepartmentName;
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
  };

  dialog = $('#dialog-form').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 'auto',
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Confirm Update": updateInfo,
        Cancel:
        function() {
          if($('#select-department option:selected').length > 0) {
              $('#select-department option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
          }
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
  });

  form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    updateInfo();
  });

  let clickedItemName, currentDepartment, currentDepartmentName;
  $('#items-table').on('click', '.item-name',  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedItemName = e.target
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
    //prefill dialog's item field
    $('#item-name').val($(clickedItemName).text());

    /* --- TODO: pre-set selected --- */
    //find item-department of the same rows
    currentDepartment = $(clickedItemName).closest('tr').find('td.item-department');
    //get clicked item's department name
    currentDepartmentName = currentDepartment.text();
    //remove old selected
    if($('#select-department option:selected').length > 0){
        $('#select-department option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    }
    //Checks for the option element which contains the department name
    //Then sets the attribute selected to that option
    $("#select-department option:contains(" + currentDepartmentName +
       ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
  })

})
```

=============================

I have a table: item names are links. A modal dialog will show up with a form when click on any item name.

[image]

The modal dialog has an input field which prefilled with item name. A drop down select and another input field.

[image]

HTML

```
<select id="#select-department">
    <option value>Bagel</option>
    <option value>Brownies</option>
    <option value>Milk</option>
</select>
```

I tried

```
let clickedItemName, currentDepartment, currentDepartmentName;
    $('#items-table').on('click', '.item-name',  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    clickedItemName = e.target
    dialog.dialog( "open" );
    //prefill dialog's item field
    $('#item-name').val($(clickedItemName).text());

    /* --- TODO: pre-set selected --- */
    //find item-department of the same rows
    currentDepartment = $(clickedItemName).closest('tr').find('td.item-department');
    //get clicked item's department name
    currentDepartmentName = currentDepartment.text();
    //set the option
    $('#select-department').val(currentDepartmentName)
```

However I found that `$('#select-department').val(currentDepartmentName)` doesn't work in my case since there's no value in `<option>`.

The drop down selections are generated by jsp.

```
          <select id="select-department" class="form-control" name="department">
            <c:if test="${departments.length() > 0}">
              <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${departments.length()-1}">
              <c:set var="department" value="${departments.getJSONObject(i)}"/>
                <option value="" >${department.optString("departmentName")}                        </option>
              </c:forEach>
            </c:if>
          </select>
```

I tried `<option value=${department.optString("departmentName")} >${department.optString("departmentName")}</option>` , but then I realized the output html cut off everything after the first space.

If anyone can point me direction that'll be great. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$('#select-department').val(currentDepartmentName)
```

To this:

```
    //Remove selected attribute of option that has selected attribute
    if($('#select-department option:selected').length > 0){
        $('#select-department option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
    }


    //This checks for the option element which contains the department name
    //Then sets the attribute selected to that option
    $("#select-department option:contains(" + currentDepartmentName + 
       ")").attr('selected', 'selected');

    //Since adding the attribute 'selected' isn't changing the drop down
    //Use .prop
    $("#select-department option:contains(" + currentDepartmentName + 
       ")").prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Hey @Ryan, `$("#select-department option:contains(" + currentDepartmentName + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');` only works once. When I click "cancel" on the dialogue and click on another item name (which will open another dialogue), the selected still showing the previous selected.

Comment: @kukumalu Then you'd need to check if any other option has attr 'selected' and remove it from that one before setting the other one. I updated my answer to remove the selected attribute from an option before changing it to another.

Comment: I updated my question with screenshot. I see old selected is removed and new one is added, but the UI still showing the old selected.

Comment: @kukumalu Try using `.prop` instead, updated my answer to give you an example

Comment: Hi @RyanWilson, I tried `.prop` and the UI is updated, presents the data correctly. But the html won't have `selected="selected"`. Is there any way to have `selected="selected"` while the UI present the correct data?

Comment: @kukumalu Uncomment the section where I had it using `.attr` but keep the section using `.prop`, edited my answer one more time for you.

Comment: yes I tried it. I can see the html have `selected="selected"` and the UI presents the right data. Thank's lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your value with data-yourField in your link, like this:

```
<a href="#" class="item-name" data-department="brownie" >Tasty Brownie</a>
```

Then use it to select your option with jquery:

```
$('#items-table').on('click', '.item-name',  function(e) {

  var department = $(this).attr('data-department');
  // open your dialog and set your elements
  $('#select-department').val(department);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Jordan. I'm not using bootstrap's modal since it doesn't clear any click even after I close the modal dialogue. I'm using jQuery UI's modal right now.

Comment: @kukumalu I've changed my code so it would look more like yours. Take a look and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: because all my data is dynamically generate, they contain spaces. When I pass them into html attribute, html cuts off everything after the first space.